# How to discern the computational graph and the corresponding gradient calculation process after I modifies the value of tensors with ".data"

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation, derivative

I am informed that modifying the value of a tensor with .data is dangerous since it can generate wrong gradient when backward() is called. However, I write two programmes(below) only to find that the generated gradient is so weird that it can't be figured out how the gradient is calculated.

The first program is like this:

```
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3.], requires_grad=True)
out = a.sigmoid()
c = out.data  
c[0]=1
c[1]=3
c[2]=4
weight = torch.ones(out.size())
d = torch.autograd.grad(out,a,weight,retain_graph=True)[0]
```

d is tensor([  0.,  -6., -12.])

while the second one is :

```
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3.], requires_grad=True)
out = a.sigmoid()
c = out.data 
c.zero_()
weight = torch.ones(out.size())
d = torch.autograd.grad(out,a,weight,retain_graph=True)[0]
```

d is tensor([0., 0., 0.])

I know the vector to vector derivative is a little complex.However, since the value of *a* and the computational flow from *a* to *out* is identical in these two programmes. So the value of *d* should nor differ from each other.

I sincerely appreciate all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i created a short colab notebook that clears up the confusion here:
[Link To Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AFL-bc3-7gINxNs_ZNP3UAj0g94-2Url?usp=sharing)

The problem seems to be that, when you create c by assigning it out.data the values in c are linked to the values in out.data. So when you zero out the c vector in your second example, the values in out.data are also overwritten with zeros. Hope I could help! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can understand what you mean. However, in my opinion, although the value of out has been changed, the value of a and how out is calculated from a remain the same(out = a.sigmoid()), so torch.autograd.grad(out,a,weight,retain_graph=True)[0] shouldn't differ in these two programmes. For example: z = xy (x=1 and y =2, so z =2 and the derivative of z to x is 2), now I change the value of z to 0, now the derivative of z to x is still y(which still equals to 2 in this example ) . So I can hardly understand why the value of z(the counterpart of output in these two programmes) counts.